# NLTK RegexpTokenizer: Regex to retain just characters in Random text

Tags: python, regex

I used `tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')` which retains alphanumeric characters
But how do I combine a regular expression to remove every other element retaining just characters greater than length 2

Below is one row in the dataframe which contains random text

`0   [ANOTHER 2'' F/P SAMPLE 01:52 ...A13232 / AS OUTPUT MSG...`

Comment: Do you think `RegexpTokenizer(r'\w{3,}')` ?

Comment: If only things were this simple! It worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need for find words with `len>2`:

```
RegexpTokenizer(r'\w{3,}')
```

Or if need only letters:

```
RegexpTokenizer(r'[a-zA-Z]{3,}')
```

Comment: Both work fine.

Comment: Super, you are welcome!